# dealing with jQuery json response from php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am running into trouble with understanding JSON responses from PHP.
So basically I am coding slider using jQuery, where user can see recent news. In this slider I want to display news heading and some text from article.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/global_functions.php",
    data: {callFunction: "getNewsTitles"},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        //what now?
    }
});
```

Using this request I am asking PHP to return me this data:

```
$resultArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT heading,text FROM news WHERE type='lielie.jaunumi' AND status='1' AND slider='1'");
for ($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++){
    $resultArray[$i]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

So in jQuery I get response of:

> [{"heading":"Ritens pie sienas tiek nozagts","text":"Zilu 2008.gada BMW m\u0113s at\u013cauties tom\u0113r nevaram"},{"heading":"Dzied\u0101t\u0101ja Aliwka par CityTaxi","text":"Teksts 123 Teksts"},{"heading":"Kvalit\u0101tes uzlabo\u0161ana P\u0101rdaugav\u0101","text":"Fant\u0101zija nozaga kaimi\u0146a ka\u0137i"},{"heading":"CityTaxi papla\u0161ina autoparku","text":"Fant\u0101zija sit augstu vilni"},{"heading":"CityTaxi iekaro R\u012bgu","text":"Te iet kaut k\u0101ds teksts, piem\u0113ram - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris pellentesque nisl id lobortis congue. Ut commodo tortor eget dapibus gravida. Sed accumsan orci ac ante dignissim feugiat."}]

Sadly I dont know how to move forward with this.
I want to make jQuery make varialbe for each heading, so I can use them later in my slider, by just typing something like "heading[1] and text[1]", but I have no idea have to do it.
Also, I am using utf8_general text, and json looks like to bug them out. Will I be fine or should I use something to fix them?